# Is there a way to put where clause on C# automapper

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, automapper

I am using automapper to map source to Destination object using below. Here the Source will have a a property called ClientInfo = "X" .

```
  cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.firstName))
  .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.lastName))
  .ForMember(dest => dest.Mail, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.email))
  .ForMember(dest => dest.Phone, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.phoneNr));
```

I want to map the source to destination only if the value ClientInfo property is X. So it is something like

```
cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.firstName))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.lastName))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Mail, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.email))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Phone, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.phoneNr));
```

//here a where clause to filter ClientInfo . Is it possible using automapper

Comment: So if ClientInfo is not “X” you want automapper to return null for the destination object?

Comment: @grin0048 thats correct. is it possible?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Conditional-mapping.html

Comment: @chambo I don’t know that conditional mapping is what they’re after. If I’m understanding correctly they want to map the source object to a destination object, but only if the source object has `ClientInfo == “X”`. If that’s the case I think that logic should be in the code that’s invoking AutoMapper. Something like `var dest = src.ClientInfo == “X” ? mapper.Map<TDest>(src) : null;`.